# "Animals!" decision tree dataset

Tags: games

I think most of you remember that old game, called "Animals!", which is a binary decision tree (y/n) that stores animals and questions.

e.g. http://cs.smith.edu/~nhowe/112/Assignments/assign.dtree.html

I am looking for a database (as big as possible) containing questions and animals, as long as they're free to use.

Comment: I guess you could try contacting http://20Q.net